# Fatal Exception: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, apache

From 16th Jun to now, I got a ton of Apache HTTP library crashes from Fabric.

I used **sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar** for Volley library.
Does anybody know the reason?

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_shutdown(NativeCrypto.java)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1091)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1085)
at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.shutdown(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:183)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.shutdown(DefaultClientConnection.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$PoolEntry.shutdown(SingleClientConnManager.java:440)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.shutdown(SingleClientConnManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.finalize(SingleClientConnManager.java:135)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something you are trying to call isn't reachable and runs into an timeout. Without actual code it's difficult to determine. Maybe certificates changed? Maybe something else changed? Maybe only specific SSL/TLS algorithms are no longer allowed.